# Powershell variable assignment vs pipeline

Tags: powershell

What is the fundamental difference between these two commands?

```
$myVar = & "notepad.exe"
```

and

```
& "notepad.exe" | Set-Variable "myVar"
```

With the first one, the command returns immediately without waiting for the exe to terminate, which was not what I expected.

With the second one (or anything else with pipeline, such as `| Out-File` or `| Set-Content`), the command waits properly for the exe to write a result in stdout and terminate.

Comment: Are you sure? What kind of program is it? Powershell should wait for the exe to finish in both cases. (Just tested this again to confirm). Can you give an actual verifiable example?

Comment: My program is LabVIEW, but I observe the same with for example notepad.exe (`$myVar = & notepad.exe` returns immediately, `& notepad.exe | Set-Variable "myVar"` only when I close the window).

Comment: So far I can only say, the difference is that in the 2nd version the program is hooked to the pipeline. This will give the same bevavior: `$myvar = & notepad.exe|%{$_}` I am note sure why exactly though.  I think it's different for an actual UI app vs console (compare ping.exe: powershell waits in both cases)

Comment: For information, my program is LabVIEW, which is also an UI app.

Answer (score 0):

Pipeline is nothing but taking the Output from the first set and passing it as an input to the second one. Pipelines act like a series of connected segments of pipe. Items moving along the pipeline must pass through each segment.

In your case, Powershell is actually waiting in both the cases. but if you use `Measure-Command`, there is a difference in execution time which is better in case of `$myVar = & "C:\path to\program.exe" $argument`

Comment: If my exe takes 10 minutes to run (which is actually the case), the 1st command will terminate immediately, the 2nd will terminate after 10 minutes.

Comment: Use Measure-Command to compare by piping it one more time. That will help you in the execution methodologies. But technically it is correct only.